# deleted folder and files details on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, aws

I have AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance. I found some missing details like source code from application and some files. Now, i want to identify which user and when it's deleted from server. So, i need details of all file and folder details which are deleted by user in past 30 to 60 day's.

May be server saves all log when user's update or delete file. So, it's possible then i need above details from server log.

Comment: Did you previously install any form of system auditing such as `auditd`?

Comment: Nothing install or configuration audit system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such logging done by default unless you previously installed some form of system auditing such as `auditd`.

It is too late in this case, but you should consider installing it for future needs.

I suppose you probably already checked your backup.  Hopefully it contains the files that were deleted.